# Enable "standby mode" for MacBook Pros

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, sleep-wake

I can't get my 2012 13" MacBook Pro to standby (note: NOT regular sleep, see http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4392).

My pmset -g results are:

```
Active Profiles:
Battery Power       -1
AC Power        -1*
Currently in use:
 standbydelay   1800
 standby    1
 womp       0
 halfdim    0
 panicrestart   157680000
 hibernatefile  /var/vm/sleepimage
 sms        0
 networkoversleep   0
 disksleep  0
 sleep      0
 hibernatemode  3
 ttyskeepawake  0
 displaysleep   10
 acwake     0
 lidwake    1
```

Anyone has any idea what might go wrong which would prevent standby? Note: regular sleep works fine, but it does not enter standby after a period of time. I also reset the PRAM and SMC.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's supported on your 13" MacBook Pro. From the [KB article you linked](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4392) (emphasis mine):

> Apple Portables that support standby mode are:
>
> - MacBook Air (Mid 2010) and later
> - MacBook Pro (*Retina, Mid 2012*)

I parse the text in italics to mean the Mid 2012 Retina MacBook Pro, not "Mid 2012 MBP *and* Retina MBP". This is further corroborated by the reference to the flash storage later on, which is only included by default on the MacBook Air and Retina MBP.

Comment: CanuckSkier is correct - the terminology is from [this site](http://support.apple.com/manuals/#macbookpro) where it's clear (retina, date) is different from (date). No non-retina MacBook Pro support this standby mode today. It's not yet clear if Mountain Lion and [Power Nap](http://www.apple.com/osx/whats-new/features.html?siclientid=5899&sessguid=bb738736-3cd4-4bb3-af1e-45d1150ff1dd&userguid=bb738736-3cd4-4bb3-af1e-45d1150ff1dd&permguid=bb738736-3cd4-4bb3-af1e-45d1150ff1dd#powernap) will expand the list of "standby" eligible hardware.

Comment: I think you might be wrong. From the pmset man page: "The setting **standby** will be visible in pmset -g if the feature **is supported on this machine**". Why would it be visible in pmset -g if it's not supported for my machine?

Comment: I think the standby option in `pmset` is similar, but unrelated to the standby function in that article. As noted in [man pmset](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pmset.1.html), it's related to the hibernation. If you google around, you can also see plenty of evidence of `standby` getting set to 1 on pre-2012 MBPs as well.

Comment: What makes you believe they are different? The functionality is the same (save RAM to disk after a period of regular sleep). Even if different, shouldn't either the `pmset` `standby` or the `article` `standby` work?

Answer (score 2):

I can get my mid-2012 15" MBP to standby. Actually I got it to work after reading this post. I noticed the requirements for standby to work in the doc http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4392

My previous failed attempts were with my USB wireless mouse plugged in. So I removed USB receiver and detach power then close the lid, then after about 5 mins my MBP went to hibernate. Here's my pmset settings:

```
# pmset -g custom
Battery Power:
 lidwake              1
 standbydelay         300
 standby              1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 hibernatemode        3
 gpuswitch            2
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 displaysleep         2
 sleep                10
 acwake               0
 halfdim              1
 sms                  1
 lessbright           1
 disksleep            10
AC Power:
 lidwake              1
 standbydelay         300
 standby              1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 hibernatemode        3
 gpuswitch            2
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 womp                 0
 displaysleep         10
 networkoversleep     0
 sleep                0
 acwake               0
 halfdim              1
 sms                  1
 disksleep            10
```

**Need to mention that I replaced the original apple internal hard disk with a SSD disk. Not sure if this is a critical factor.**

Comment: What exactly (which commands) did you do to change the settings?

Answer (score 0):

By the way, my Macbook Pro (non-Retina and with normal HDD) can hibernate (hibernatemode 25) and standby (hibernatemode 3 standby 1).

For standby, it only does so if power is disconnected and there are no USB devices attached.